# How to set height automatically for CarouselSlider

Tags: flutter, dart

I use the CarouselSlider package to swipe cards horizontally. The cards contain texts that have different lengths. Currently, I have set the height with MediaQuery, but the height is not always enough, because some texts can be very long. Without height setting the CarouselSlider is only very small, and the height is not taken from the child. How can I set the CarouselSlider to automatically adjust the height based on the text length?

```
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,    // How to auto set height
            initialPage: _initPage,
            enlargeCenterPage: false,
            viewportFraction: 0.925,
            enableInfiniteScroll: false,
          ),
          items: [
            DreamViewDetailCard(
              dream: dream,
            ),
            DreamViewAnalysisCard(
              dream: dream,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

```
class DreamViewDetailCard extends StatelessWidget {
  DreamViewDetailCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.dream,
  }) : super(key: key);

  Dream dream;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 50),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            DateSeparator(dreamDate: dream.dateOfDream!),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: colorPaperSurface,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    dream.title ?? '',
                    style: textStyleTitleOnPaper,
                  ),
                  buildPublicationIcon(),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 8),
              Text(
                dream.story ?? '',
                style: textStyleNormalOnPaper,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Image 1) Text card with less height `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`

Image 2) Text card with more height `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`

Image 3) Text card `without height settings`

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you get better results with setting `aspectRatio` instead of `height`?

Comment: How should I set the ratio? I did not get a good result. If I set the height too large or the ratio too small, I get a lot of empty space after the card.

Comment: There is a related post where someone nested ```BoxFit``` in ```aspectRatio```. In general, working with a fitted box might help. See this post: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-fittedbox-widget-examples

Comment: I am not sure if this works with CarouselSlider. I can't get it to work.